# Hot to define a fallback mapping temmplate in AWS Api Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a POST method exposed though an API in AWS API Gateway. It would process a certain JSON. But there is a weird requirement: I am supposed to accept anything and return always a 200 status code (as long as the service is available and working of course).

So if I receive a call with Content-Type: image/jpeg, application/xml or what/ever, I must be able to map the request to my Lambda function.

I have achieved to map any request to a custom type using the VTL (Velocity Template Language), the issue is that I must specify every single Content/Type I want to support in the Integration Request.

I would like to define a fallback mapping template for every Content-Type that is not among those that I have already defined. It is not allowed to specify "*/*" as Content-Type.

I can not use `When no template matches the request Content-Type header` option as passthrough because b y default the lambda function tries to deserialize the body from a JSON format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you *should* enable the `When no template matches the request Content-Type header` option.  [As documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html) your Lambda will get an API Gateway event.  This event has a `headers` field that, on a POST should contain a `content-type` field.  If your code understands the content-type then handle it.  If not, return a response that has the correct status code and whatever is appropriate.  This is not on the API gateway side but rather on the Lambda side.

See [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/handling-arbitrary-http-requests-in-amazon-api-gateway/) for some additional ideas.